# Is it possible for a file to occupy a fraction of a byte?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems

I connected my GoPro on my laptop running Windows 10. I browse its files via Windows Explorer. I selected all files in a folder, click on Properties, and I see that the number of bytes is a float, not an integer (since it ends with `.00`). This made me wonder: is it possible for a file to occupy a fraction of a byte?

[image]

Comment: Just because something is displayed with fractional digits (even if it were a non-zero fraction) does not mean it was floating-point internally. _Many_ business applications in COBOL handle fractions in fixed-point but almost never use floating-point. Multics did support file length with a granularity of one bit, but it didn't use bytes, so your concept 'fraction of a byte' does not exist at all in that context.

Comment: my guess is someone passed a float in somewhere they arguably should have used a long, but I guess that the first thing I think of, is that a system architecture defines a byte-size (as well as nibble, word, dword, etc) for that architecture, and compatible hardware will use registers and bus-widths and blocks and whatever else based on that atomic unit. for instance in x86, you extract a nibble from byte, because the hardware is going to give you a byte, whether you like it or not. it is possible to use less than a byte, but no modern filesystem would support it really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files and folders do not use a fraction of a byte, just the whole next byte, or actually the next whole block depending on the actual file structure.

I cannot duplicate your display on Windows 10 or 11, but to say again, data does not use just a fraction of a byte.

Comment: Always weird stuff going on with MTP protocol ..

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong.  Files and folders require a the next whole BLOCK - which will be a power of 2 and dependent on the filesystem and block size - and almost always 512 bytes or greater on anything not ancient.    To the extent you might argue otherwise, if you are storing multiple files in a compressed archive it would be possible for a file to be a fraction of a byte but that is a representation of a stream is not relevant here.

Comment: I was just being simplistic to answer the question. Yes, of course, the next whole block and I amended accordingly

Comment: @davidgo while the atomic unit of capacity occupied by a file is always a multiple of a filesystem block (which in turn is of a size that is a multiple of the logical block), the atomic unit of the size of a file is still byte. Otherwise you would get "unexpected" trailing zeroes (NULs) (or perhaps even, indeterministic data) when you read a file. (Yet I can't recall a case in which a file can have "sub-byte" size.)

Comment: @TomYan: Wasn't it CP/M (predecessor of MS-DOS) that only counted file size in whole sectors? I recall that's why Cmd's `copy` still has the "text" mode where ^Z acts as the end-of-file marker... I don't think I've heard of any system using sub-byte precision, though, at least not since everyone agreed on bytes being 8 bits.